# ¿cómo capturo datos enviados desde Spring con JQuery?

Tags: jquery, spring

> Desde Framework Spring envío un dato de sesión llamado "***tipoOperario***" y muestro el formulario "***frmDatosIniciales.jsp***" ...

```
    public ModelAndView cargarInicio(
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {      

    ...
        WebUtils.setSessionAttribute(request, "tipoOperario", tipoMenu);

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("frmDatosIniciales");
        return mv;

    ...
}
```

> Dentro del código del formulario "frmDatosIniciales.jsp" llama a...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="a/js/ingresoBootstrap.js"></script>
```

> En ***ingresoBootstrap.js*** es donde quiero llamar al dato("*tipoOperario*") de sesión enviado  desde Spring y asignarlo a un "input".
>
> Les muestro el código...; quisiera saber cómo se hace correctamente usando JQuery, por favor me indican cualquier comentario, gracias.

```
$( document ).ready( function () {

$("#tipoOperario").val('<c:out value="${tipoOperario}"/>');
...

});
```

> En el código HTML de ***frmDatosIniciales.jsp*** el input que quiero asignar el valor de sesión ***tipoOperario*** está de esta manera.

```
<input id="tipoOperario" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que estas teniendo es probablemente debido a que los ficheros js no son parseados por el servidor.

Puedes hacer varias cosas

1.- Añadir al fichero jsp el código javascript necesario para asignar los datos que te vienen del servidor añadiendo lo siguiente a un fichero jsp

```
<script>var tipoOperario=<c:out value="${tipoOperario}"/></script>
```

2.- También puedes escribir directamente los datos en un input

```
<input id="tipoOperario" type="text" value="${tipoOperario}">
```

Si no quieres que sea visible

```
<input id="tipoOperario"  type="hidden" value='${tipoOperario}'/>
```

Y después con jQuery obtienes el valor

```
$('#tipoOperario').val()
```